# ClassNotFoundException in Java Agent Instrumentation premain

Tags: java, classloader, instrumentation, agent, javaagents

I read https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation and I'm trying to instrument the `doService` method in `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, which is part of the Spring Boot framework, i.e. `spring-webmvc.jar`.

This is the way I start my spring boot application:

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

I understand my agent's `pom.xml` should package/include the `javassist` dependency but I don't expect the agent should package/include the jar `spring-webmvc.jar` containing the class `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, as it is already packaged and contained in `myapp.jar`

In the `premain` of the agent, when I try to instrument and load the class `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` by using `forName`, it throws the `ClassNotFoundException`.

How should I instruct the agent to load it from the `myapp.jar` ?

Thank you!

```
        try {
            targetCls = Class.forName(className);
            targetClassLoader = targetCls.getClassLoader();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Successfully obtain target class {0} and its classloader using 'forName' with class loader {1}", new Object[] {className, targetClassLoader.toString()});
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Class {0} not found with Class.forName. {1}", new Object[] {className, ex.getClass().getCanonicalName()});
        }
```

Comment: Why do you wish to load the class manually? Is it not enough to register an instrumentation transformer and transform the target class during class-loading? Furthermore, what kind of JAR is your application? A shaded one or one with a special classloader that dynamically locales and unpacks nested JARs inside the uber JAR? It would be helpful to see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub. Make it as minimal as you can, while it still reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. You're right that I don't have to load the class manually and I should just register the transformer in `premain` and then do the instrumentation code inside the `transform` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java instrumentation and following this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation#loading-a-java-agent), note that manually invoking `forName` is not necessary in the example. What you can do is to register the transformer in `premain` and then in `transform` method, check for your target class name and start the instrumentation as instructed in the link. Happy coding!